# tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio replacement?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ffmpeg

In the tensorflow docs, it stated that tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio is depreciated, however it does not state what it's replacement is...

> THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2018-09-04. Instructions for updating: This will be deleted and should not be used.

Here is the link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/ffmpeg/decode_audio

Comment: `tf.contrib.ffmpeg` relies on ffmpeg actually being available in your environment, which makes them kind of context-dependant. I imagine that TensorFlow developers prefer not to have ops that may work in one machine but not in another. You could replace it with a [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) that does the decoding, maybe with something like [audioread](https://pypi.org/project/audioread/) or [this script](https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/85d70bf53e207bab3775), which would be essentially the same thing, and at least it shows the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

two replacements for `tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio` are available for  tensorflow 2.0:

- Tensorflow 2 will have a [builtin wav decoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav)
- The ffmpeg ops from `contrib` move to a new external [I/O project](https://github.com/tensorflow/io). However the audio ops are [not implemented yet](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/49).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22320191)

Comment: my post __did__ answer the question. I rephrased it to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use TensorFlow to decode audio files. You can use another Python library (although you might be slowed down by the GIL).

The [tensorflow-io](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io/) library now has [`AudioIOTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/audio/AudioIOTensor) as an interface for decoding audio files while also keeping track of their audio sample rates. You can use it as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

audio_tensor = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor("filename.flac")
print("Sample rate is", int(audio_tensor.rate))
# tensor = Decoded audio as a tf.Tensor of shape (frames, channels).
tensor = audio_tensor.to_tensor()
print(tensor.shape[0], "frames containing", tensor.shape[1], "channels")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try 
`tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.audio_ops.decode_wav`.

This might be gone in tensorflow 2